# Spring ApplicationListener gets fired twice on webapp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an application listener that's supposed to execute only once per webapp startup, since it loads basic user info data.

```
public class DefaultUsersDataLoader implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent e) {...}
}
```

Somehow, it gets executed twice: on app startup and when the first request arrives to the server. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Comment: I had the same problem. Removing the @EventListener solved the problem. Would someone have an explanation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally in a Spring MVC application you have both a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`. Both components create their own `ApplicationContext` which in turn both fire a `ContextRefreshedEvent`.

The `DispatcherServlet` uses the `ApplicationContext` as created by the `ContextLoaderListener` as its parent. Events fired from child contexts are propagated to the parent context.

Now if you have an `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` defined in the root context (the one loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`) it will receive an event twice.

Comment: Thank you. I ruled it out with an `e.getApplicationContext().getParent() != null`, but it seems a bit hacky. I wonder if there is a better practice around?

Comment: Not really, you could toggle a boolean if the listener was already invoked. If it is just to load some data and you are using Spring 4.1 you could also use the [`SmartInitializingSingleton`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/SmartInitializingSingleton.html) instead.

Comment: You may also wish to ensure that the web context does not instantiate any beans other than your controllers. i.e. Enforce the component scan base packages to only include a 'web' package, which is parent to controllers and other such beans. This ought to ensure that your listener only exists in the root context, and will therefore only pick up root context events.

Comment: Thanks, looking at event.applicationcontext (id, and parent and grandparent) (in our case for the closeEvent) gave us a better understanding of the context configuration and hierarchy of each caller (servlet ctx in addition to the root app context).

Answer (score -1):

Do not annotated your Listener Class's method with @EventListener